# Chrome's memory can't release by use 'alert' of javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

my Chrome version :  50.0.2661.94 (64-bit)  in OS X

when i called javascript's alert or confirm in my code,
chrome's memory will not take off but will continue to grow.

here is my test code.

script:

```
    window.onload =function(){
        document.getElementById("confirm").onclick = doConfirm;
        document.getElementById("confirm2").onclick = doAlert2;

    }
    var doConfirm = function(){
        var rec = confirm("test test test test test test test");
    }
    var doAlert2 = function(){
        alert("test test  test test test test test test test ");
    }
```

html:
`<button id="confirm">set</button>
<button id="confirm2">set</button>`

then I press the button constantly, 
and see Activity Monitor of Chrome's memory.
I also try other Version (49.0.2623.112 m) and other Browser(FireFox)
But the same problem does not occur...

any solution?

Comment: All relevant code should be pasted directly into your question as text and not in an image.  External links are not sufficient here as a code reference because they have a habit of getting changed or disappearing over time ruining the ability for questions to be a long term reference source.  Also, you must explain how you measured that chrome's memory will continue to grow as that is very important in whether you actually a leak or not.

Comment: sorry guys , I immediately corrected

Comment: Code should be posted as text, not as screenshots.

Comment: @jfriend00 OK, thanks for your warn

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is to be expected: Whenever you use built-in methods `alert`, `prompt`, or `confirm`, your main UI execution thread is halted until the user responds to the box that appears. However this does not prevent Chrome (or any browser) from performing other tasks in the background that continue to consume memory (eg. add-ons, Web Workers, etc.)

The recommended approach to prevent this is to not call the aforementinoed methods, but instead use DOM-rendered input elements to perform the confirm, alert, or prompting functionality that you need.

Comment: thanks for your answer. but it dosen't happen on old version( ex: 49 ) or other browser , and my work use it so many , i'm 
confused.